# Adding space and font changes to second <li> in the <ul>

Tags: html, css

I am working on changing some html elements on a structure of  and inner

I added a css element like this:

```
ul.spaced li 
{ 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
}
```

And I try to use it like this:

```
<li class="spaced">Hike description test</li>
```

But it doesn't seem to add the space at the bottom.

Also, how can I make the inner

font non-bold (it is set to be bold in the above elements)?

You can see an example of the page I am working on here:
http://www.comehike.com/community/hiker_public_profile.php?community_member_id=2

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong - you don't want to look for `li inside ul.spaced`, you want `li.spaced inside ul`. Also, if `margin-bottom` doesn't work, you can probably get away with just changing it to `padding-bottom`.

```
ul li.spaced
{ 
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Nice! That worked like a charm. It lets me accept the answer in 10 min, and I'll do that then. :)